# Software or library for creating images of ball and stick models?

Tags: molecular-structure, software

Is there any code library (in any programming language) or software capable of producing images of ball and stick diagrams?

Example of an image of a ball-and-stick model for Ammonia:

[image: Ball and stick diagram for Ammonia]

([Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ammonia-3D-balls.png))

Preferences:

- It should be capable of producing images programmatically through a code library. Any mainstream programming language (C, Java, Python, etc.) is acceptable.
- It should be able to take chemical descriptions as input to produce images of ball and stick diagrams as output.
- It should be free and open source.

I know that it is possible to create these models using Mathematica's [ChemicalData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChemicalData.html) built-in symbol, but I am looking for something that can integrate better into my existing code base (hence the preference for free and open source libraries in mainstream programming languages).

Comment: You should try  JSmol,  it is free and easy to use.  Have a look at one of the many Wikipedia pages that use this for drawing molecules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For general open source solutions:

- [Avogadro](https://www.openchemistry.org/projects/avogadro2/) - Molecular editor GUI. Has a Python API.
- [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/) - Chemical structure viewer. Fully scriptable using a custom scripting language. It also has a JavaScript-only version named 'JSmol', allowing models to be displayed in web browsers.
- [ghemical](http://www.bioinformatics.org/ghemical/ghemical/index.html) - Has a GUI for editing molecules, but no API.

For a $\LaTeX$ solution, see this question on the $\TeX$ Stack Exchange site: [Help creating solid cylinders along a path in Tikz for crystal lattice diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114815/help-creating-solid-cylinders-along-a-path-in-tikz-for-crystal-lattice-diagram/114876#114876)

Other solutions:

- If you have access to Mathematica (e.g. on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian [which comes with a free copy of Mathematica]), you can use Mathematica's [ChemicalData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChemicalData.html) built-in symbol to create ball and stick models.

Answer (score 4):

I would also mention [QuteMole](http://qutemol.sourceforge.net/fxs/):

> QuteMol is an open source (GPL), interactive, high quality molecular
>   visualization system. QuteMol exploits the current GPU capabilites
>   through OpenGL shaders to offers an array of innovative visual
>   effects. QuteMol visualization techniques are aimed at improving
>   clarity and an easier understanding of the 3D shape and structure of
>   large molecules or complex proteins.

[image]